# How do I delete a class in Ecognition?

Tags: ecognition

I have used the software Ecognition to create a land cover & land change map. I used the class Barren in two images. However, I do not want to use the class Barren anymore. I have reclassified the image objects classified as Barren to a separate class. I cannot remove the class Barren from the Class Hierarchy window.

When I chose delete or delete class I get the following error message:

```
cannot delete class because it is in use
```

My only other option is to delete all the classes which I cannot do because I did some manual classification. Please help me figure out how to delete one class without deleting the entire classification in the image.

Comment: What does google say about that? I believe eCognition has many undiscovered bugs and this one may be raised with the support team. They are pretty attentive.

Comment: Use `Remove classification` with Barren class and you'll be able to delete it. You can delete it if you have some objects classified as Barren.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem as well.  From what I remember, it can be that if you have features that are associated with a class active in the Image Object Information window, this can stop you being able to delete a class, even if it isn't actually in use.  Check if there are any features that you used to classify the "Barren" class open in the Image Object Information window and remove them if so (they can always just be added back in after if need be) and then try to delete the class.